# Doctrine, which event should be used to change related field on field change?

Tags: doctrine-orm

Doctrine have preUpdate event. However in it code can only change those fields that where already changed.

So if user changed field address and only it, code can not update other fields, like latitude and longitude.

Which other doctrine even could be used to achieve such functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onFlush is probably what you want.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush

Inside your callback you can determine if the address has changed and then set lat/long accordingly.  Pay careful attention to the $unitOfWork->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($classMetadata, $entity) requirement.

A somewhat easier approach that does not require getting into the unit of work stuff would to use the preFlush event.  In this scenario you would have to add some sort of flag to your entity to determine if the address has changed.  Which could be a pain but avoids the unit of work stuff.